# ngResource $promise error handling?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have the following controllers which all the `ngResource` services to get data.

```
.controller('venueCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, VenueService) {
    $scope.venue = VenueService.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
})
.controller('tomorrowCtrl', function ($scope, EventService) {
    var evts = EventService.query({ period: "Tomorrow" });
    evts.$promise.then(function (response) { $scope.events = response; });
}).....
```

Now I need to add error handling (for example, display an alert box) for the error situations, e.g., no network, web service failed, etc. How to add the code to handle the errors?

Comment: The second parameter for `then` function is the error callback ! is that what you mean ?

Comment: How about the first`Get`?

Comment: All the resource instances and collections have the `$promise` property.

Comment: So I need to convert the first one to promise too to handle error? Will there be any behave change?

Comment: You can use the get parameters `get(([parameters], [success], [error])`.

Comment: If you want to handle all ngResource server errors please let me know ;)

Comment: Yes I want to handle all the errors. Basically display some error messages if not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Interceptors` this way:

```
angular.module('ngRessourceErrorsHandler', [])
.config(function($resourceProvider) {
    angular.forEach($resourceProvider.defaults.actions, function(action) {
        action['interceptor'] = {
            responseError: function(httpResponse) {
                //Do whatever you want here !
            }
        };
    })
});
```

Please try this and let me know if this works for you. Don't forget to add `ngRessourceErrorsHandler` dependency to your module or just use `config` directly.

Comment: Can I just add the Interceptors setup code in `angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () { ..../* insert here? */ .... }`?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can ;) `angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives']).run(...).config(...`

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try when I have a chance.